# Attaching to Gtk::Grid the same image

Tags: c++, c++11, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

** EDIT: What I have tried is below (compiles but strangly does not work)**

```
class NibblerWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
private:
    Gtk::Grid grid;
    Gtk::Image tmp;
    Gtk::Image gridElem[5];
public:
    bool initImgArray();
    NibblerWindow();
    ~NibblerWindow(){}
};

bool MyWindow::initImgArray()

{

int i = 0;

while (i != 5)
    {
       this->gridElem[i].set("someimage.gif");  
       ++i;
    }
return true;
}

MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
    this->set_title("Work in progress");
    this->set_default_size(512, 512);
    this->add(grid);
    this->grid.add(gridElem[0]);
    this->grid.add(gridElem[1]);
    this->grid.show();
    this->grid.show_all_children();
}
```

Hello everybody,

I am basically trying to build a **game grid** (like draughts or checkers), with each child widget containing the same image pattern. The only functional method I found was to create each child widget individually, and build them in the constructor list of my class, like this:

```
class MainWindow {
private:
    Gtk::Grid gameGrid;
    Gtk::Image gridElement1;
    Gtk::Image gridElement2;
    Gtk::Image gridElement3;
    Gtk::Image gridElement4;
    /* and so on ... */
    /* with some member functions */
public:
    MainWindow();
    ~MainWindow();
};

MainWindow::MainWindow() :
    gridElement1("background.png"),
    gridElement2("background.png"), gridElement3("background.png"),
    gridElement4("background.png") /* et caetera ...*/
{
    this->add(grid);
    this->add(gridElement1);
    this->gameGrid.attach_next_to(gridElement1, gridElement2, Gtk::POS_LEFT, 40, 41);
    this->gameGrid.attach_next_to(gridElement2, gridElement3, Gtk::POS_LEFT, 40, 41);
    this->gameGrid.attach_next_to(gridElement2, gridElement2, Gtk::POS_LEFT, 40, 41);
    /* et caetera */
}
```

I do not find it appropriate, especially for this case, to instantiate in a such a static manner my objects... I would like to initialize them in some kind of **loop**.
I have tried many times in many ways to put them in **vectors** or **arrays**, but it showed it does not work... Considering that we should not manipulate direct pointers of **Gtk::Objects** but **Gtk::RefPtr** instead.

Does someone know another manner to declare my Image objects ?

Comment: How does using an array not work? What did you try?

Comment: I tried by creating an array of `gridElement[x]`, but then I could not fill it with my file name because of the `Gtk::Image(std::string &file)` constructor being `private`. I then succeed to build a `vector<Gtk::Image *>`, but dereferencing the `Image *` pointer in the call of `attach_next_to` makes a Segmentation Fault, probably because the pointer not being a `Refptr` smartpointer.

Comment: Is there no `Gtk::Image::set_from_file()` method in gtkmm? That would do what that constructor does.

Comment: Yes there is, but how would you call it from a array ?

Comment: @andlabs Hello, I have put some more code with the call of the `set(std::string &)` function from an array. It does display nothing...

Comment: Did you forget to call the `initImgArray()` method in your complete program? Once I added that to the constructor and called the `show_all()` method in `main()` it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you ! It works very well ! It seems like I forgot to call my `initImgArray()` member function. The two images display themselves when I call `show_all_children()`as well as from my `main()` as from my constructor. :)